# Fiddler doesn't capture iPad traffic

Tags: ipad, fiddler, capture, traffic, loadrunner

Fiddler is installed on my windows machine, ipad wifi setting are 'manual' and setting the windows machine as proxy.

When running fiddler echo service from the ipad browser it is shown in fiddler, but no other http request from the ipad, either browser or ipad app, is captured in fiddler.

How can this be solved?
My final goal is creating a capture file of the traffic during an ipad app usage, and configure it to `loadrunner` for a load test.

Comment: If you're *only* seeing the Fiddler Echo Service traffic and not any other traffic, your IPAD's proxy settings aren't set correctly (or you have 3G and didn't disable it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LoadRunner 11.52 (latest) you can simply use the new Proxy Recording feature and it should solve all your issues.

Or you can check [this thread](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/Using-Loadrunner-to-record-HTTP-traffic-being-captured-in/td-p/5565517).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proxy recorder for HTTP as far back as LoadRunner version 5 to capture external host generated HTTP traffic...and that incliudes all iDevices, Android Devices, Windows Phone Devices, Palm|WebOS Devices, the Macbook next to you, the LINUX workstation next to that one and the UNIX box two states over.   As long as you have a network connection and can redirect the HTTP proxy on the host you can grab it.

For all version of LoadRunner prior to version 8, the proxy recorder is the default recording engine.   Just select external application, redirect your proxy on the tablet and away you go.  For versions 8 and above, choose old recording engine from the recording settings, external application and then redirect your proxy.  For 11.5x there is a new Proxy hook on a new port which is branded as new and unique.  But, pretty much it's a new pretty skin on something that has been there in the product for (at least) since 1998.

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner 11.52 proxy recording works great!

I haven't tried the old recording engine though prior to 11.52